# Strange bug - Some elements are visible when I run app from Xcode, but not if I start running the app from device

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

Context: Native iOS app developed with Swift which manages external control units via bluetooth. I use Xcode Version 14.2, but it used to happen with older versions as well. Tested on devices with iOS 15 and 16.

In a specific section what the app has to do is:

- take the data through the Bluetooth input and output
- go to the outputs screen and present the outputs
- from the outputs screen go to the inputs screen and show them

The problem is as follows.
If I take a physical iPhone and connect it to the Mac, then start the app from Xcode, everything works fine.
If, with the same iPhone, I start the app not from Xcode but with a tap from the iPhone screen, the app starts correctly, connects via Bluetooth, shows all the outputs correct, while for the inputs they are all correct except the last. The last one is never displayed, all the others are.

The main problem is that I don't know how to debug since it only happens when the app starts unlinked from Xcode. Does anyone know of other ways to troubleshoot the problem or have had similar problems and know of possible solutions?

Comment: You can try good old `print` debugging: add messages at strategic places that you think might be involved/should be called. You can then connect your iPhone to your Mac via USB and view its messages via `Console.app`. Then start your app and analyze the output.

Comment: I created for such cases additional screen with logged info. So instead of printing it I save logs into the file and view it directly from the same application during testings. Maybe overkill, but I like to see logs directly from the app

Comment: @DarkDust I try with your way, I add some print messages but I can't see them in Console app. For example I print "---zzzzz---" and there isn't any string like this and I'm sure that function is called. Have you a suggestion to fix this problem with console app?

Comment: Use `NSLog` instead.